# Sending inline email attachments on Google App Engine Php

Tags: php, image, google-app-engine, embed, inline

How do you do an in-line image embed in appengine php?
Does it need to be base64?
I see the 
$message->addAttachment
but how do I reference it inside the html that I am assembling?

With swiftmailer I would just

```
$SMap = PUBLIC_ROOT . "images/sample.jpg";
$type = pathinfo($SMap, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($SMap);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
$ImageCode = "<img style=\"padding:0 50px 0 0;\" src=\"" . $base64 .     "\" alt=\"Image\" />";
```

and just insert the image display code where I wanted it, but I don't see any reference material on this or I can't locate it for some reason for php appengine native email.

Answer (score 1):

Inline attachments are done using content-id.
Docs [source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/#PHP_Sending_mail_in_PHP)

```
$image_data = file_get_contents($SMap);
// Notice that $image_data is the raw file data of the attachment.

$ImageCode = "<img style=\"padding:0 50px 0 0;\" src=\"cid:img1\" alt=\"Image\" />";
$message = new Message();
$message->setSender("from@google.com");
$message->addTo("to@google.com");
$message->setSubject("Example email");
$message->setHtmlBody($ImageCode);
$message->addAttachment('image.jpg', $image_data, "img1");
$message->send();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a little clearer than the docs. But the docs forced me to do some research, and since cid doesn't fly with Google Yahoo et al and deliver-ability is everything in this case, think I will punt on the images and stick with href  links to pages and html.

Comment: @user3674714 we use it in our mailers and gmail and yahoo mailers works perfectly fine

Comment: Thank you, guess I will do a step down then, images first, no response, html, then text only. I have had so many problems with deliver ability on a traditional setup with swift-mailer it was really a leg breaker